# Wygwam 3 no longer show table borders

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

Since updating to Wygwam 3, when you add a table it no longer shows table cell guides. So all you see is nothing. No way to see which cell you are in or even if a table was inserted at all. I understand that you can attach a style sheet to the Wygwam field and style the table that way... but it seems like a major usability issue that by default now tables are basically invisible. Is there anyway to fix this and make guides show up by default?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this absolutely sucks.

There is a workaround, try the following:

1) In the CP under addons -> modules -> Wygwam -> editor configuration (your actual configuration, click on the name) specify a file in the field "css file", if you not already did so. probably it makes sense to store it in a folder themes/third_party/wygwamAssets (but this has no effect on functionality).

2) create this file and enter some code to make the table-border visible, e.g.

```
table, td, tbody, tr, td span { border : 1px solid black;}
```

maybe you have to clear your browsers cache to see the effect. for me this worked.

Comment: Or even `1px dotted black`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Wygwam 3.2.1 and EE 2.7.2. By default Wygwam shows cell borders. I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version of Wygwam and EE.

[image: Wygwam 3.2.1 table]

Comment: Correct, it does show borders when you specify a border size. I am actually referring to when you have border set to 0. In that case, what it did previously was still show you a light dotted border to indicate where the table cells were. What the newest version now is display nothing. While it is technically displaying the correct style (since I indicated no borders), it makes it impossible to know where the cells are... or even if a table was added at all without looking at the source code.

Comment: I updated my original post to show what I am talking about.

Comment: I see. I get the same result as you. As such, I'd report it directly to Pixel and Tonic as a bug.